# SQL produced by Entity Framework for string matching

Tags: sql, entity-framework

Given this linq query against an EF data context:

```
var customers = data.Customers.Where(c => c.EmailDomain.StartsWith(term))
```

You’d expect it to produce SQL like this, right?

```
SELECT {cols} FROM Customers WHERE EmailDomain LIKE @term+’%’
```

Well, actually, it does something like this:

```
SELECT {cols} FROM Customer WHERE ((CAST(CHARINDEX(@term, EmailDomain) AS int)) = 1)
```

Do you know why?

Also, replacing the Where selector to:

```
c => c.EmailDomain.Substring(0, term.Length) == term
```

it runs 10 times faster but still produces some pretty yucky SQL.

**NOTE:** Linq to SQL correctly translates StartsWith into Like {term}%, and nHibernate has a dedicated LikeExpression.

Comment: Have you seen how yucky assembly or MSIL gets after your nice looking linq or any good c# source code? Question is if it gives correct result, why do we need to bother.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about replacing StartsWith with Substring - that fixed my problem with the StartsWith version not matching empty strings as prefixes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [linq to entities generated sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576803/linq-to-entities-generated-sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that CharIndex is a lot faster and cleaner for SQL to perform than LIKE. The reason is, that you ***can*** have some crazy "LIKE" clauses. Example:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE EmailDomain LIKE 'abc%de%sss%'
```

But, the "CHARINDEX" function (which is basically "IndexOf") ONLY handles finding the first instance of a set of characters... no wildcards are allowed.

So, there's your answer :)

EDIT: I just wanted to add that I encourage people to use CHARINDEX in their SQL queries for things that they didn't need "LIKE" for. It is important to note though that in SQL Server 2000... a "Text" field can use the *LIKE* method, but not CHARINDEX.

Comment: Whilst a Like can be slower than a CharIndex, it is much faster when used in the context of StartsWith (i.e. Like {term}%). In this case, the query optimiser is able to make use of existing indices.

Comment: "The reason is that CharIndex is a lot faster and cleaner for SQL to perform than LIKE." This is not a valid statement. People most commonly use only one or two % signs in their LIKE, and a trailing-only wildcard (i.e. LIKE 'xxx%') allows index seeks to be used, whereas CHARINDEX forces a table scan.

Comment: *The reason is, that you can have some crazy "LIKE" clauses*. No, EF is a wrapper that already knows what kind of filter I am performing. Why it is substituting the `StartsWith` with an inferior SQL filtering mechanism that cannot leverage the index.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about MS SQL server but on SQL server compact LIKE 'foo%' is thousands time faster than CHARINDEX, if you have INDEX on seach column. And now I'm sitting and pulling my hair out how to force it use LIKE.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/1b835b94-7259-4284-a2a6-3d5ebda76e4b

Answer (score 0):

Performance seems to be about equal between LIKE and CHARINDEX, so that should not be the reason. See [here](http://bytes.com/groups/ms-sql/81467-using-charindex-vs-like-where) or [here](http://204.9.76.233/Community/forums/p/16120/95084.aspx#95084) for some discussion. Also the CAST is very weird because CHARINDEX returns an int.

Comment: Trailing-only wildcards (i.e. LIKE 'xxx%') can use index seeks.  CHARINDEX does not, so that is a prime example where performance can be far superior for LIKE (which is pointed out in your first link). But I agree the CAST is confusing.

Comment: *Performance seems to be about equal between LIKE and CHARINDEX*. Performance of CHARINDEX is hugely inferior compared to LIKE for simple cases like `LIKE prefix%` in presence of index.

Answer (score 0):

charindex returns the location of the first term within the second term.

sql starts with 1 as the first location (0 = not found)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx

i don't know why it uses that syntax but that's how it works

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it is no faster, I was retrieving tens of thousands of rows from our database with the letter i the name. I did find however that you need to use > rather than = ... so use

```
{cols} FROM Customer WHERE ((CAST(CHARINDEX(@term, EmailDomain) AS int)) > 0)
```

rather than

```
{cols} FROM Customer WHERE ((CAST(CHARINDEX(@term, EmailDomain) AS int)) = 1)
```

Here are my two tests ....

```
select * from members where surname like '%i%'    --12 seconds

select * from sc4_persons where ((CAST(CHARINDEX('i', surname) AS int)) > 0)  --12 seconds

select * from sc4_persons where ((CAST(CHARINDEX('i', surname) AS int)) = 1)  --too few results
```