# linq to entities generated sql

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-entities, sql-like

I am having some problems with linq to entities in the ado.net entity framework. Basically what I'm doing is this:

```
var results = (from c in companies
    where c.Name.StartsWith(letter)
    select c);
```

and this gets translated to SQL as something like:

```
WHERE (CAST(CHARINDEX(@p, [Extent1].[Name]) AS int)) = 1
```

which is fine but my table has millions of records so this runs VERY slow. What I need it to generate is something like:

```
WHERE Name LIKE @p + '%'
```

I'm searched high and low and cannot find any solutions except to either use a stored procedure or use entity sql...

Is there any way to do this through linq? Possibly by somehow extending the linq to entities linq provider, or somehow intercepting the command tree or generated query?

Comment: It's this kind of thing which makes me very relunctant to throw away my stored procedure layer in favour of anything which generates SQL.

Answer (score 3):

I am not a SQL expert but guessing that both syntaxes:

WHERE (CAST(CHARINDEX(@p, [Extent1].[Name]) AS int)) = 1

and

WHERE Name LIKE @p + '%'

will result in either a table scan or ideally an index scan. Bottom line they will perform the same. I verified this by viewing the execution plans below. Bottom line, you need to rethink your database schema or how your are performing your search. This is not a LINQ issue.

One possible area for improvement: insure that you have indexed the column that you are searching on.

[alt text http://download.binaryocean.com/plan1.gif](http://download.binaryocean.com/plan1.gif)

[alt text http://download.binaryocean.com/plan2.gif](http://download.binaryocean.com/plan2.gif)

Comment: Provided you have an index on the Note/Name column and cardinality's not too low, it will be used on a LIKE 'a%' query. I'm not sure the query optimizer will be able to use the index for a CAST(CHARINDEX()) operation.

Comment: I have an index on the Name column of my database. The LIKE does an index scan, the generated SQL (CHARINDEX) does a table scan which is why it takes so long.

Comment: *Bottom line they will perform the same*. False. In presence of index their performance hugely differ.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, that is a truly bizarre way of doing it! Note that LINQ-to-SQL (in this case) uses `LIKE @p0 + '%'`... very odd.

Which EF provider (database) are you using? SQL Server?

As you say, a stored procedure will the the job, but you shouldn't *have* to do that... very, very odd...

Comment: Yes I'm using SQL Server 2005. From what I've read, LINQ to SQL provides a SqlMethods class that exposes SQL functions and operators such as LIKE but there's no such thing in LINQ to Entities. Go figure...

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](http://www.thedatafarm.com/blog/CommentView,guid,3f476e16-90b5-4e49-bb46-be8042f7ef79.aspx) with Linq to Entities. Unlike LIKE, apparently this construct doesn't use indexes.

We've had some success using Substring (which translates to SUBSTRING). The execution plan is similar, but in our case the query executes far quicker.

It's another "I'm sure it will be fixed in EF 2"...  :-(

Answer (score 0):

Is "letter" a char? If you made it a string, what happens?

```
var results = (from c in companies
    where c.Name.StartsWith(letter.ToString())
    select c);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using this syntax instead

```
Name.Substring(0, 1) == "E"
```

This SQL is generated

```
WHERE N'E' = (SUBSTRING([Name], 0 + 1, 1))
```

Maybe this is more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a real like in Link to Entities quite easily

Here's what's needed to make it work:

Add

```
    <Function Name="String_Like" ReturnType="Edm.Boolean">
      <Parameter Name="searchingIn" Type="Edm.String" />
      <Parameter Name="lookingFor" Type="Edm.String" />
      <DefiningExpression>
        searchingIn LIKE lookingFor
      </DefiningExpression>
    </Function>
```

to your EDMX in this tag:

> edmx:Edmx/edmx:Runtime/edmx:ConceptualModels/Schema

Also remember the namespace in the `<schema namespace="" />` attribute

Then add an extension class in the above namespace:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    [EdmFunction("DocTrails3.Net.Database.Models", "String_Like")]
    public static Boolean Like(this String searchingIn, String lookingFor)
    {
        throw new Exception("Not implemented");
    }
}
```

This extension method will now map to the EDMX function.

More info here: http://jendaperl.blogspot.be/2011/02/like-in-linq-to-entities.html